# Deleting multiple Rows based on other Colums Value in R

Tags: r

I hope someone can help me find the right direction for my Problem
Let's say we have a data frame like this

| year | Plant |
| --- | --- |
| 2009 | Monstera |
| 2010 | Monstera |
| 2011 | Monstera |
| 2012 | Monstera |
| 2014 | Monstera |
| 2009 | Pilea |
| 2010 | Pilea |
| 2011 | Pilea |
| 2011 | Philodendron |
| 2012 | Philodendron |
| 2013 | Philodendron |

I want to remove all rows of a plant if the year starts 2009 but want to stop if one year is skipped
the final data frame should look like this

| year | Plant |
| --- | --- |
| 2014 | Monstera |
| 2011 | Philodendron |
| 2012 | Philodendron |
| 2013 | Philodendron |

I the forum I found some information on this problem in excel, however I can't get it to work since I'm an absolute programming and R beginner.

Here are my code Ideas which currently don't work

```
list1<-list(unique(plants))

For (i in list1){
     if (dataset$year==2009){
     while i 
     -[c(year==2009)]
     ....
 break
  } else {
    ....
```

I know its not much but I really tried and I hope someone can help

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the logic correctly, you could try this approach.

Using the `dplyr` package, put your `dataset` into groups, based on the `Plant` as well as consecutive years (where there is a difference of 1 year between rows, such as 2009, 2010, 2011...).

Then, keep or `filter` the rows of data where the `first` year of each group is not 2009.

The final `ungroup` and `select` will remove the made-up `Group` column so your results only include `year` and `Plant`.

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
  group_by(Plant, Group = c(0, cumsum(diff(year) != 1))) %>%
  filter(first(year) != 2009) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Group)
```

**Output**

```
   year Plant       
  <int> <chr>       
1  2014 Monstera    
2  2011 Philodendron
3  2012 Philodendron
4  2013 Philodendron
```